# Strange overflow behaviour in OpenLayers v6.1.1 ol.Overlay

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers for a school project.

In my map, I load `GeoJSON` Point features as a `VectorLayer` on top of a base `mapbox` layer. The points represent buildings. When the points are clicked, an `ol.Overlay` tooltip is shown containing the name of the building.

When the tooltip is generated in the center of the screen, it looks great:
[image: Tooltip in center of screen]

When I drag the map such that the point goes close to the **right** edge of the screen, the tooltip prevents the contents from overflowing, which is really neat:
[image]

However when I try to do the same for the **left** edge of the screen, I don't get this behaviour, and instead the tooltip contents simply overflow:

[image]

Suppose the user were to click on a point that was close to the **left** edge of the screen. If the name of the building was long, the tooltip will be generated with half of it spilling out of the left edge of the screen, which is a little jarring.

May I know what properties I should set under `ol.Overlay` to fix this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1: Here is a JSFiddle that shows the behaviour. Try dragging the map such that the tooltip is near the right and left of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/meeps/kosx7w9d/4/**

Comment: It may be related to the css for the element used by the overlay

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I'll open a Github issue on the main repo because the styling is performed by the library and I have no way to control that other than editing the source code myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is the CSS that is causing this.

### Issue

[image: demonstration of problem and accompanying CSS]
When the tooltip is up against the right side of the screen, we see that it has a positive left value.

This **"pushes"** it against the right side of the screen and thus the text wraps as the tooltip tries to fit between `left: 340px` and the right side of the screen by decreasing its width.

The tooltip is "squished" between `left: 340px` and the right side of the screen.

[image: demonstration of problem and accompanying CSS]
Now, we have the tooltip off the left side of the screen. Notice that it uses a negative left value `left: -63px` to achieve the appearance of being off the left side of the screen. Having this negative value **"pulls"** the tooltip off the screen so to speak. It thus isn't "squished" and is even being pulled to the left, hence it does not shrink its width and just goes off the screen.

### Solution

[image: solution]
So we can use a large right value `right: 300px` to push our tooltip into the left side of the screen and have it shrink its width to fit.

You would want to have JavaScript to detect when to use `left:` and when to use `right:` values to position the tooltip when the user drags the map to get your desired behaviour on the tooltip.

:D

Comment: Thanks - I'll open a Github issue on the main repo since the position styling is performed by the library on the overlay container - there is no way to change this behaviour other than editing the source code.